# Get value of a field not declared in FormType

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form declared in `nameType.php` and the view render all field but I want add another field manually.

Form:

```
<form action="{{ path('create') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="text" value="2">
   </form>
```

And get the values in the controller:

```
$form->bindRequest($request);
```

How can I collect the value of the input in the controller?

Answer (score 65):

If you are trying this because the form is linked to your entity field you can add a field to FormType as not mapped. Then you do not need getters and setters on your entity.

```
->add("inputName", "text", array("mapped"=>false, "data"=>2, "label"=>false))
```

To get the data in the controller:

```
$form->get("inputName")->getData();
```

Comment: Thanks @albert this is the right way to do it. The one that asked should check this as the right answer.

Comment: what if the input is multiple select?

Comment: You should get an array with the selected values

Answer (score 4):

You can not retrieve the `input` value from the `$form`, because it's not part of it.

You have to retrieve it from the `request` in the `Controller` by using the `name` attribute :

HTML : `<input type="text" value="2" name"var_name">`

Controller: `$request->request->get('var_name')`

Comment: In the case of dynamic form it look like the only solution form me. Thx man you saved my day

Answer (score 3):

> how could collect the value of the input to the controller?

The instant-gratification way would be to use

```
$form->get('inputName')->getViewData()
```

for an unmapped field. But I'm sure there are better ways which are Symfony validation-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `$form->bindRequest($request)` you can call: `$form->getData()` to get input from user.

But if you want to receive input data for field that is not mapped you need to use mentioned `$request->request->get('field_name')`.