# Method "email" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in SqliGestionCongeBundle:Default:add.html.twig

Tags: php, symfony

How can i add text fields in my form knowing that it does not exist in my entity!!

i have this in my twig :

```
 <form action="{{ path('add_conge') }}" method="post">
<h1>{{ 'Envoyer une demande de cong&eacute;'}}</h1>

 <div>
{{ form_errors(form.email) }}
{{ form_label(form.email, 'Email Collaborateur:') }}
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
</div>

<div>
{{ form_errors(form.dateDepart) }}
{{ form_label(form.dateDepart, 'Date depart:') }}
{{ form_widget(form.dateDepart) }}
</div>
//...
```

and i get this exception:

```
 Method "email" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in SqliGestionCongeBundle:Default:add.html.twig
```

Comment: Can you please add the code from your formType or where you're generating the form?

Comment: You don't have a field with the name 'email' in the form type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get value field not declared in nameType.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745880/get-value-field-not-declared-in-nametype-php)

Comment: i don't have field  'email' in my !! form type

Comment: i have juste this in my Form Type:                                                public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
 {
  $builder
   ->add('dateDepart', 'date', array(
          'input'  => 'datetime',
             'widget' => 'choice', 
           ))
   ->add('dateRetour', 'date', array(
             'input'  => 'datetime',
             'widget' => 'choice',
           ))
  ->add('nbreJour')
  ->add('justificatif')
  ->add('dateDemande', 'date', array(
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'widget' => 'choice',
         ));

  
 }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745880/get-value-field-not-declared-in-nametype-php) you don't have that field in your form type.

To add a field that's not mappend with the entity/formType you need to do the following:

```
//where you're creating your form with the formbuilder
->add("email", "email", array("mapped"=>false);
```

This will add a field to your form that is not related with the entity.

To receive the data from it just do this in the controller/action where you're handling the form:

```
$form->get("email")->getData();
```