# Symfony FOS User Bundle - Remove Username in Form and View

Tags: symfony

Using this Link

[Remove / Replace the username field with email using FOSUserBundle in Symfony2 / Symfony3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832916/remove-replace-the-username-field-with-email-using-fosuserbundle-in-symfony2)

I tried to remove the Username from the registration form by Overriding the FOS User Bundle.

Form Type class is working fine.

But while rendering, it throws

**Method "username" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in FOSUserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig at line 3**

I tried with this link to avoid this

[Method "email" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist in SqliGestionCongeBundle:Default:add.html.twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910707/method-email-for-object-symfony-component-form-formview-does-not-exist-in-sq).

I couldn't. 
Need expert assistance regarding this.

***Update 1:***

I also tried this link

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html

Form Type class:

/*
 * Overridden FOSUserBundle RegistrationFormType.
 */

namespace Test\RegistrationBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType

{

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->remove('username',array("mapped"=>false));
}

public function getParent()
{
    return 'fos_user_registration';
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'app_user_registration';
}
```

}

Twig File:

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Matteo, Please assist me in this. It would be greatly helpful

Comment: can you please add your template code and form type code

Comment: Hi @NandaKumar, it's really the best solution if you provide the code of the used twig-file and the FormType-file. Then it will be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @jahller and @D3myon comments. It helped me to diagnose the problem.

I had overridden the template form by including them as individual elements instead of form_widget(form).

I removed the username in the template file.

Problem Solved.

Comment: That sounds good. But keep in mind, that in special cases, you will have to remove a part of a form. Then you can call the `remove()` - function inside the controller directly after building the form.